# How do i calculate a tower vision radius?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, isometric

Iam making a isometric tower defense games, i was trying find some good way to make the tower enemy detection, than i find that formula:

*Given tower position (Tx, Ty) and enemy position (x, y). And tower vision radius (rx and ry)*

```cs
float a = (x - Tx);
a = a * a / (rx * rx)
float b = (y - Ty);
b = b * b / (ry * ry)

bool enemyInRange = a + b <= 1;
```

I dont know how calculate the tower vision radius since its a isometric game than rx will be depending my camera angle (x = 60º)

Another problem is that formula wont work perfectly cause some enemys have a different hitboxes size (will be a elipse too), so just enemy position wont be enough.

Comment: I honestly don't really understand what you are asking for .. could you throw in some screenshots / sketches of what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you use orthogonal isometric projection with a view angle of 60 deg, the linear mangling coefficient is appr. 0.82 constantly. Since Z axis is mangled by a different coefficient `sqrt(3)/2`, just adopt your formula by multiplying the axial distances by 0.82 for X and Y, then calculate the radius and experiment with mangling on Z with multiplication by `sqrt(3)/2`.

If you use oblique frontal projection when the Y axis is projected on the screen plane rotated CW by 45 deg angle, the mangling coefficients are 1 for the X and Z axis, and 0.5 for the Y axis, so you should build the projected vision radius as an ellipsis by the following equation:

```
[pow(x, 2) / pow(R, 2)] + [pow(y, 2) / pow((R / 2), 2)] = 1
```

Comment: For x and y? I thought was only X since y stay same on isometric view,like when i put a any shape i Just need put x=60 to be isometric, to be real i modify y too but, x = 60° and y = 45°

Comment: @TenerPVPs it depends on the actual projection you use. If you use an orthogonal view, as I explained, the mangling coefficient is identical to the ones I indicated. Otherwise, if, as you said now, you use oblique frontal isometry, I explained in the renewed answer.

Comment: Done with the small delay.

Comment: I see, could we continue that on discord? Iam not the best one with math :), Still have some questions If you are free to answer, i also can show the isometric view i have

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have a Discord instance on my workstation. If you prefer, it is better to write me a message on Twitter, then go somewhere else.

Comment: i followed you on twitter, can you enable me send a message?

Comment: Done, please check